# Updated Web App .Net 4 to 4.7.2 running on Visual Studio Debug but not on IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-8.5

I've recently updated a web app using .Net 4 to use .Net 4.7. When I debug through Visual Studio 2019, the web app opens correctly, but when using IIS to route to the web directory, it no longer runs.

I host a web app on a virtual machine and use iis to route traffic to the respective site. The web app used to run on .Net 4 but I just recently updated it 4.7. I am able to run the site locally using visual studio debug, but when it comes time to deploy it cannot serve the page correctly.

When opening the site through IIS, I get the following 
[error message through IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu8Ll.png)

When accessing the site through the site name, I get the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58rn5.png)

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty new to IIS and I believe the issue is with IIS as I can serve up the pages through VS debug

Comment: Your 500 error should result in an event log entry being written. You can check that by launching Event Viewer. The other error indicates something wrong with SSL. Do you have a certificate assigned? Does the certificate name match the DNS name you're using?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: @mason Thanks for your comment. Do you know where in the event viewer I should be looking for the logs? And yes, I do have a cert assigned but never ran into this issue before updating the .net version

Comment: Generally Windows Logs > Application within the Event Viewer.

Comment: @mason Thanks. I'll take another look there. When I first looked, nothing seemed to stand out as being related to the issue I was having

Comment: set Web.Config <customErrors> to off.  it will be shown to the user. (the “yellow screen of death screen”)

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper I set it to off and it still results in "500 - Internal server error" page

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have .net4.7.2  install in your server 
second, make sure that the .Net Roles and Users are set in IIS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am unable to make those changes in my server. But on IIS under Application Pools, I do have all pools referencing the correct version of .NET CLR Version v4.0.30319. Any other ideas?

Comment: it seems you are running CLR File is not included .Net 4.7.X  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installedhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

Comment: can you see if .Net 4.7.X is installed in the server?

Comment: The link you posted gives a "post not found" error. Additionally, on my local development computer, I am using the same CLR Version and I can access the site through IIS. So I don't believe it is a CLR Version Issue

Comment: How to: Determine which .NET Framework versions are installed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: .NET Framework versions and dependencies  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

Comment: are you running the server on your local?

Comment: So I've checked on my local (development) computer and on the virtual machine that hosts the site and they both have the same CLR Versions and .Net Versions (4.7.2). And what do you mean am I running the server on my local?